# Cold boot on appengine with java8

Tags: google-app-engine

I've deployed the helloworld samples on appegine standard using **java7** and **java8** runtimes and noticed that **java8** takes in average 6 times longer to spin up a new instance. I've used **B1** instances on my tests but noticed the same on **B2** as well and I am not willing to use more expensive instance classes because currently I have no traffic at all.

is it because **java8** is still BETA or a limitation that we should consider regarding **java8**?